# How to telnet and collect logs, Whenever the IP is alive/active?

Tags: python, subprocess, telnet, ping, os.system

PING:

```
import os   
ip=1.1.1.1
o=os.system("ping "+ip)
time.sleep(10)
print(o)
if res == 0:
 print(ip,"is active")
```

Telnet:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
tn.write(command+"\r\n")
f=open(filename,w)
while True:
 response = tn.read_until("\n")
 f.write(response)
```

Here, In between IP goes down. During that time i need to ping that IP & whenever it comes up i need to start collecting logs again. How can i do this ?

Actually, I need to collect logs through telnet (which is indefinite). I could able to do it. During this process, IP from which i'm collecting logs goes down. So, I need to track on this IP (Ping). Whenever IP comes up again, I've to start collecting the logs again. It would be great, if you can help me on this.

**I found the solution:**

```
tn=telnetlib.Telnet(IP)
    tn.write(command+"\r\n")
    f=open(filename,w)
    while (os.system("ping -n 1 IP") == 0):
     response = tn.read_until("\n")
     f.write(response)
    else:
        call some module for telnetting again/goto

     But, here is it possible to hide the console when we use (os.system(ping)). I know it can be done through subprocess. But since os.system is a one liner & very easy to verifY the result also.
```

Comment: "hide console" seems like a separate issue (there are already several questions about it on StackOverflow). If you found a satisfactory solution; post it as an answer instead of  editing the question.

Comment: what happens if the host is down during `tn.read_until("\n")` call?

Comment: @ Sebastin: If the host is down, then it follows the else part doesn't execue while block. So, it doesn't encounter tn.read_until("\n") .

Comment: What happens if you remove `os.system()` and allow `tn.read_until("\n")` to run anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is what you're looking for?

This snippet will start a ping process, and block until it sees the output "bytes from" or until it times out (1 minute by default):

```
import pexpect

def wait_until_online(host, timeout=60):
    child = pexpect.spawn("ping %s" % host)
    child.expect("bytes from", timeout)
```

Comment: Timing can be anything. Not only a minute.

Comment: You could set it to something higher, like 24 hours = 86400 seconds. `wait_until_online("example.com", timeout=86400)`

Comment: If you _really_ want it to run indefinitely, you can catch the `pexpect.TIMEOUT` exception and simply try again.

Comment: Thank you André Laszlo. I'm sorry, if i have not been clear above. Actually, I need to collect logs through telnet (which is indefinite). I could able to do it. During this process, IP from which i'm collecting logs goes down. So, I need to track on this IP (Ping). Whenever IP comes up again, I've to start collecting the logs again. It would be great, if you can help me on this.

Comment: Try something like: 1) collect logs normally, 2) catch any exceptions related to the host going down (timeouts etc), 3) use the function above to wait for the host to resurrect 4) goto 1

Comment: @ André Laszlo : I have pasted a solution above. Could you please help me on that ?